# Loop with awk output field

Tags: linux, bash, awk

the output of my script

```
grep 'Interface GigabitEthernet' * | \
sed 's/104-8-20-23.lightspeed.gnvlsc.sbcglobal.net/104.8.20.23/g' | \
sed 's/0.0.0.0: //g' | \
sed 's/.log:/ /g' | \
sed 's/Line protocol on //g' | \
sed 's/, changed state to//g' | \
awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$12" "$13'} | \
sort -u -r -k 5,5 -k 4,4 | \
awk '!seen[$5]++'
```

is

```
104.16.7.57 Jul 5 07:19:53 GigabitEthernet3/0/5 up
104.16.7.57 Jul 5 06:42:46 GigabitEthernet3/0/41 up
104.16.7.57 Jul 5 02:01:31 GigabitEthernet3/0/34 up
104.16.7.57 Jul 5 02:02:17 GigabitEthernet3/0/33 up
104.16.7.57 Jul 5 04:52:45 GigabitEthernet3/0/28 up
104.16.7.57 Jul 5 05:39:23 GigabitEthernet3/0/26 up
104.16.7.57 Jul 5 04:21:49 GigabitEthernet3/0/22 up
104.16.7.115 Jul 5 05:23:13 GigabitEthernet2/0/9 up
104.16.7.115 Jul 5 05:16:15 GigabitEthernet2/0/8 up
104.16.7.115 Jul 5 04:04:36 GigabitEthernet2/0/7 down
104.16.7.115 Jul 5 04:00:34 GigabitEthernet2/0/6 up
104.16.7.115 Jul 5 04:00:35 GigabitEthernet2/0/5 up
104.16.7.57 Jul 5 06:33:29 GigabitEthernet2/0/25 up
104.16.7.57 Jul 5 03:37:20 GigabitEthernet2/0/24 up
104.16.7.115 Jul 5 00:31:31 GigabitEthernet2/0/20 up
104.16.7.115 Jul 5 02:34:06 GigabitEthernet2/0/2 up
104.16.7.115 Jul 5 00:30:38 GigabitEthernet2/0/19 up
104.16.7.115 Jul 5 00:30:50 GigabitEthernet2/0/18 up
104.16.7.115 Jul 5 05:04:16 GigabitEthernet2/0/10 up
104.16.21.95 Jul 5 08:13:05 GigabitEthernet1/0/6 up
104.16.21.95 Jul 5 05:51:39 GigabitEthernet1/0/47 up
104.16.21.95 Jul 5 04:00:30 GigabitEthernet1/0/45 up
104.16.21.95 Jul 5 04:00:39 GigabitEthernet1/0/44 up
104.16.21.95 Jul 5 05:00:47 GigabitEthernet1/0/43 up
104.16.7.57 Jul 5 08:13:15 GigabitEthernet1/0/40 up
104.16.7.57 Jul 5 05:00:47 GigabitEthernet1/0/3 up
104.16.21.95 Jul 5 05:29:38 GigabitEthernet1/0/28 up
104.16.7.115 Jul 5 03:12:24 GigabitEthernet1/0/27 up
104.16.21.95 Jul 5 05:52:01 GigabitEthernet1/0/25 up
104.16.21.95 Jul 5 05:52:42 GigabitEthernet1/0/24 up
104.16.7.57 Jul 5 06:51:12 GigabitEthernet1/0/13 up
104.8.20.24 Jul 5 07:32:50 GigabitEthernet1/0/12 up
```

I want to apply the snmpwalk command with the IP value of firts field in a loop

```
 snmpwalk -v1 -c public $1 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0

 $ snmpwalk -v1 -c public 10.0.2.20 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0
 iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 = STRING: "C3725"
```

to concatenate the result on each line so that the output is

```
 104.16.7.57 C3725 Jul 5 07:19:53 GigabitEthernet3/0/5 up
```

but I don't know how to do this part.

Answer (score 2):

You can take your existing pipeline and pipe it into a shell loop:

```sh
grep 'Interface GigabitEthernet' * \
| sed '
    s/104-8-20-23.lightspeed.gnvlsc.sbcglobal.net/104.8.20.23/g
    s/0.0.0.0: //g
    s/.log:/ /g
    s/Line protocol on //g
    s/, changed state to//g
  ' \
| awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $12, $13}' \
| sort -u -r -k 5,5 -k 4,4 \
| awk '!seen[$5]++' \
| while read -r ip rest; do
    string=$(
      snmpwalk -v1 -c public "$ip" 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 \
      | awk -F '"' '{print $2}'
    )
    printf '%s %s %s\n' "$ip" "$string" "$rest"
  done
```

Notes:

- I collected all the sed commands into a single sed invocation.
- all the grep/sed/awk/sort commands can be written as a single awk command.

Comment: I have tested and it works perfectly. I was completely stuck on this code and your solution has helped me learn and make my bash code better. Thank you so much.